# Image not insert in database using php files

Tags: php

The images column in my database is blank when I click the upload button also .... I tried using $_POST['images'] then the image is stored in db but thats of no use the error is:

```
<code>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Image testing...</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="file" name="images" id="images" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>

<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test_event');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
    $query = "INSERT INTO products (id,image) VALUES('','$image')";
    $qry = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $sth = $conn->query($sql);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg:base64,'.base64_encode($result['image']).'"/>';
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
?>
</code>
```

> Notice: Undefined index: images in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\image.php on
>   line 17 
>           Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in 
>           C:\xamp`enter code here`p\htdocs\admin\image.php on line 17**

Comment: add in your form enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Also using `addslashes()` on the contents of the image will most likely corrupt the image! If you have to store the file on the database, then `base64_encode()` the file before storing it to the database and dont use `addslashes()` on it

Comment: Can you check further where the error occurs? Can you manage to store it properly, or is the main problem displaying it afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to your form tag.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

More info

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `enctype` tag to the form to tell PHP and the browser how to interpret the form data.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="images" id="images" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

The files metadata will then be available at `$_FILES['images']`